# Tooltip attached to mouse in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, tooltip

How do I get a tooltip that is attached to the mouse cursor using C#? I'm trying to achieve an effect like the following, a small tooltip showing the status of Ctrl / Shift / Alt keys.

I'm currently using a `Tooltip` but it refuses to display unless it has about 2 lines of text.

```
tt = new ToolTip();
tt.AutomaticDelay = 0;
tt.ShowAlways = true;
tt.SetToolTip(this, " ");
```

In mouse move:

```
tt.ToolTipTitle = ".....";
```

[image: tooltip]

Comment: I've added my current code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I don't think there is any way you could do this purely with managed code. You would have to go native.

The way I see it there are two options.

1. P/Invoke the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Set the `hwnd` to your target window and pass in a `TTM_ADDTOOL` message and a [TOOLINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure for the lParam.  This is useful when you want a tooltip on an external window you haven't created (one that isn't in your app). You could get its hwnd by calling [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

   See how all this is done here in [this article.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2417/Display-ToolTip-in-any-place-on-the-screen)  You just have to add the P/Invoke.
2. Apparently you can use the `CreateWindowEx()` function with `TOOLTIPS_CLASS` as a classname and it will generate a tooltip for you. Something like this:

   ```
   HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
                           WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                           hwndParent, NULL, hinstMyDll,
                           NULL);

   SetWindowPos(hwndTip, HWND_TOPMOST,0, 0, 0, 0,
            SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
   ```

   See the whole article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760250(v=vs.85).aspx

---

To get you upto speed, you would have something like this defined in you .NET code. I got the definition from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/createwindowex.html?diff=y).

You will find all the structures I've mentioned in my answer on the same website (or other similar ones) Once you have defined all of them in your code, you can then easily transpose/port the C samples that are in my answer and the linked articles.:

```
class NativeFunctions 
{
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
   WindowStylesEx dwExStyle, 
   string lpClassName,
   string lpWindowName, 
   WindowStyles dwStyle, 
   int x, 
   int y, 
   int nWidth, 
   int nHeight,
   IntPtr hWndParent, 
   IntPtr hMenu, 
   IntPtr hInstance, 
   IntPtr lpParam);
}
```