# How to set tooltip at current mouse location?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I registered Hotkey: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Hotkey message is sent to:

```
private void Hotkey_press()
{
... // I want to show tooltip "Hello" at current mouse location.
}
```

Is there any way to show this tooltip even the mouse doesnt point to any control and it is outside my Window.Form1?

**Edit: That ToolTip can show even the form lost focus or hide**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want something like

```
ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
IWin32Window win = this;
tt.Show("String", win, mousePosition);
```

Where the `MousePosition` can be obtained from the `MouseEventArgs` via

```
private SomeMouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Point mousePosition = e.Location;
    ...
}
```

or using

```
System.Drawing.Point mousePosition = Cursor.Position;
```

also, you may want to set a longer duration for which the `ToolTip` is displayed, well just use the overloads available for the `Show` method, `tt.Show("String", win, mousePosition, 5000);` will display the tool tip for 5 seconds.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank. It helped me while my Form is focusing. And if my Form1 is hiding, not active then this ToolTip tt is not show. Is any way to show it even the Form1.Hide() ?

Comment: -1 because this only works if the form is in focus. Also, `MousePosition` needs to be converted to client coordinates with something like `this.PointToClient(MousePosition)`

Comment: This answer is wrong. Why is it marked as answer and why does it have 5 up-votes????

Comment: @Elmue no, it is not wrong at all. It is likely that you are not setting the duration of the tool tips display. If you use `tt.Show("String", win, (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2), (int)(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2), 5000);` you should see a tool tip with "String" pop up in the center of your screen for 5seconds. I can confirm to you that this indeed works having just confirmed this myself. Also, this is _WinForms_, not WPF. Happy coding...

Comment: The code is wrong because mouseposition gives absolute screen coordinates and TooolTip.Show() takes only coordinates relative to the owner window "win". The tooltip will always be limited to the bounds of "win" and cannot be anywhere on the screen where the mouse currently is. If "win" is not a huge window that spans over all existing monitors, this code will not work. The question says clearly: "even the mouse doesnt point to any control and it is outside my Window.Form1?"

Answer (score 3):

```
Tooltip tip = new ToolTip();
tip.ShowAlways = true;
tip.Show("My tooltip",this,Cursor.Position.X,Cursor.Position.Y);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.showalways.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx

Comment: Thank. It work when Form1 is active. Is any way to show this Tooltip even Form1.Hide() ?

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong about that, it seems that this is not possible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44atyhsa.aspx

Comment: This answer is wrong. All coordinates must be relative to the control "this". But mouse coordinates are absolute.

Comment: this is the correct answer, although not to the actual question, with the exception of it missing the conversion from screen to control coords. i.e. `this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X`

Answer (score 2):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11098897/1378739) suggests, there is no managed way to accomplish this. If you want to show a tool tip control when your program is not in focus then the "right" way to do it is to PInvoke Win32 and use `CreateWindowEx`. The answer linked above given by gideon shows some pointers on how to do it, but nonetheless it is very complicated.

If you don't mind using thrid party libraries, [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) provides a way to create tool tips easily without having to deal with Win32 yourself.

Here is a very simple example demonstrating use:

```
//make sure AutoItX3.dll is referenced in your project
using AutoItX3Lib;

private AutoItX3 myAutoIt = new AutoItX3();

private async void ShowToolTipAtMouse(string message)
{
    //default position is bottom right of mouse pointer,
    //but you can set the x and y positions yourself
    myAutoIt.ToolTip(message);

    //call the function again with an empty argument to close
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    myAutoIt.ToolTip(String.Empty);
}
```

This will work as long as your program is running; doesn't matter if it is in/out of focus or even hidden. Downside is you don't get the regular fade out animation (it just vanishes). Also, if you need multiple tool tips at once you need to have multiple `AutoItX3` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need Show/Hide it in the mouse events, also converting mouse location from Screen coordinate to your control coordinate. the little problem is if you put tooltip exactly on mous pointer location toolTip will catch mouseEnter event and unintended mouseLeave event on your control will be triggered so my solution was adding a little offset to final location.

```
        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = pictureBox3.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            p.X += 5;
            p.Y += 5;
            toolTip1.Show("My tooltip" ,
                pictureBox1, p);

        }


        private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.ShowAlways = false;
            Text = ("Leave");
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
            Text=("Enter");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a shame Winforms does not have a position property for tooltips.

The easiest thing I found is to add your own mouse-over and mouse-leave handlers and then use the Show() function to set the location (x and y), in pixels, relative to the upper left corner of the second argument of the Show() function.

The second argument can be any control, but probably makes most sense to use the control containing the tooltip itself (this), the parent the control, or a child control inside the control.

You can use a Point instead of two arguments (x and y) for the position, but remember Show() will take the point's x coordinate and y coordinate and add them to the x and y coordinates of the upper left corner of the control you chose as the second argument.

```
        private void UserControl1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.Show("this text is so new", this, 10, 10);
        }

        private void UserControl1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(this);
        }
```