# How to display different tool tips on different regions of a control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display different tool tip text depending on what part of a control the user has their mouse over. As a simplified example, this will display "Left" if the user hovers over the left half, and "Right" if the user hovers over the right half:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    private ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();

    public TestForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TestForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.X < Width / 2) {
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this, "Left");
        } else {
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this, "Right");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this causes the tool tip to display immediately and also follow the cursor around. Is there any way to make it behave like the different regions are separate controls?

Comment: How to set tooltip at current mouse location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885785/how-to-set-tooltip-at-current-mouse-location

Comment: @user2316116 I don't want it to show immediately though. I want the hover delay that tool tips normally have

Comment: You may want to consider using a Timer and a Label and coding it all yourself, since the behaviour you want differs considerably from a standard ToolTip..

Comment: `ToolTip` component from WinForm does not support regions at all :( It works for whole control only.  So you can easly use it for buttons, labels, picture, but not for regions of window (like ListView or TreeView). And this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timer that will trigger tooltip on delay when mouse is not moved.

Add timer with some interval, say, 1000 ms (1 sec).

```
public TestForm()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

While mouse moves it should run

```
private void TestForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    //if (e.X < Width / 2) {
    //    toolTip.SetToolTip(this, "Left");
    //} else {
    //    toolTip.SetToolTip(this, "Right");
    //}

    timer1.Stop();
    timer1.Start();
}
```

And if stopped, trigger a tooltip

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();

    if (PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X < this.Width / 2)
    {
        toolTip.SetToolTip(this, "Left");
    }
    else
    {
        toolTip.SetToolTip(this, "Right");
    }
}
```